# Can't access rabbitmq management interface via vm docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect to rabbitmq management interface via vm that I created on Azure portal using docker. However, even though rabbitmq is started, cant access the ports.

P.S. the management plugin is enabled. I did almost everything on the internet however still no progress.

I used commands such as:
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management

Also tried to dockerize a rabbitmq instance using docker containers. Also no progress.

I got already binding port error however I killed the ports and run again so there was no issue with it. Still no access to `localhost:15672`.

Comment: Arguments to docker (such as `-p` for port publishing) must come **before** the image name in your `docker run` command line. Any arguments after the image name are passed into the image.

Comment: Oh my mistake that I wrote the command wrong here. I am already using this command as you mentioned, not the way I wrote here.

Comment: Then you should **edit your question** so that the command line you show reflects the command line you're actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone also trying to solve this issue, I solved it by adding an inbound port (15672) to the VM via Azure.